# how to move from local development to production?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and haven't been able to find the right flow. I'm getting confused.

Here is what I have: 1 production server (A) and various local machines (X)

What I have done yet:

1. Git Init(iated) my project folder on (A)
2. Git Clone(d) in my Dropbox folder on (X)
3. Developped a new feature locally (X), tested it and tried to push it to (A)

Then of course I realized (A) being not a bare repo I would have had to deal with version issues..

What I want:

1. Git to be nice and easy
2. Develop new features on (X) and push my commits to (A) (changes
   should be immediate)
3. Be able to make changes directly on (A)
4. Be able to add a "development" server between (A) and (X) to the
   scheme without too much trouble

I know I ask for a lot but I have looked into bare repositories, git flow,.. but I'm not sure what solution would best suit me.

Comment: is it possible in your case, that instead of being pushed to, (A) pulls changes from somewhere else?

Comment: @riza (A) could pull the changes but not from the local repo right ?

Answer (score 0):

assumed that you have an access to execute git commands in (A), its better if you have 2 git repos in (A), one a bare Repo, and the other is a working tree, at a little price that is to do one more command when updating (A).

you could do something like this:

1. init a bare repo in (A) in a path, let say /path/to/bare/repo.git
2. clone a project folder in (A) from bare repo, let say in /path/to/running/repo/. This one is not a bare repo

Developer could push changes to the bare repo in A. When all seems well, the running repo pull changes from bare repo.

With this, adding a 'development server' is as easy as clone from the bare repo. Of course this setting don't comply with your statement that changes to (A) should direct and immediate. But I think its better if you compromise that.

If you really want to have only one non-bare repo in (A), you could changes the branch in that repo. You could do something like this:

1. init a non-bare repo in (A)
2. change the branch of that repo with command such as: `git checkout -b production`

Do all development in master branch or whatever branch other than 'production'. When changes are pushed to repo in (A) in their respective branch, merge it to branch production with `git merge`.